# how to return an array from a script in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

suppose I have a script called 'Hello'. something like:

```
array[0]="hello world"
array[1]="goodbye world"
echo ${array[*]}
```

and I want to do something like this in another script:

```
tmp=(`Hello`)
```

the result I need is:

```
echo ${tmp[0]}  #prints "hello world"
echo ${tmp[1]}  #prints "goodbye world"
```

instead I get

```
echo ${tmp[0]}  #prints "hello"
echo ${tmp[1]}  #prints "world"
```

or in other words, every word is put in a different spot in the tmp array.
how do I get the result I need?

Comment: Can you make `Hello` a function rather than a separate script?

Comment: well, I probably will have to use it in 2 different scripts, so instead of writing the function twice I rather use a script.

Comment: @littlerunaway, there's middle ground between those -- creating a library of shared functions, and sourcing it into both scripts.

Answer (score 6):

Emit it as a NUL-delimited stream:

```
printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}"
```

...and, in the other side, read from that stream:

```
array=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
  array+=( "$entry" )
done
```

This often comes in handy in conjunction with process substitution; in the below example, the initial code is in a command (be it a function or an external process) invoked as `generate_an_array`:

```
array=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
  array+=( "$entry" )
done < <(generate_an_array)
```

---

You can also use `declare -p` to emit a string which can be `eval`ed to get the content back:

```
array=( "hello world" "goodbye world" )
declare -p array
```

...and, on the other side...

```
eval "$(generate_an_array)"
```

However, this is less preferable -- it's not as portable to programming languages other than bash (whereas almost all languages can read a NUL-delimited stream), and it requires the receiving program to trust the sending program to return `declare -p` results and not malicious content.

Comment: well, since we haven't seen pretty much any of these in class, I don't think I can use it. but I think I found a way around my problem

Comment: @littlerunaway, your class won't let you learn anything from outside sources? That's... silly; everything used in this answer is included in the bash manual, and I'd hope your class would encourage you to use that as a reference.

Comment: bash is a relatively small part of the course. I guess they don't want us to get too deep into it at this point, and that everything we did see in class should be enough

Answer (score 3):

Although there are workarounds, you can't really "return" an array from a bash function or script, since the normal way of "returning" a value is to send it as a string to `stdout` and let the caller capture it with command substitution. [Note 1] That's fine for simple strings or very simple arrays (such as arrays of numbers, where the elements cannot contain whitespace), but it's really not a good way to send structured data.

There are workarounds, such as printing a string with specific delimiters (in particular, with NUL bytes) which can be parsed by the caller, or in the form of an executable bash statement which can be evaluated by the caller with `eval`, but on the whole the simplest mechanism is to require that the caller provide the name of an array variable into which the value can be placed. This only works with bash functions, since scripts can't modify the environment of the caller, and it only works with functions called directly in the parent process, so it won't work with pipelines. Effectively, this is a mechanism similar to that used by the `read` built-in, and a few other `bash` built-ins.

Here's a simple example. The function `split` takes three arguments: an array name, a delimiter, and a string:

```
split ()  { 
  IFS=$2 read -a "$1" -r -d '' < <(printf %s "$3")
}
```

eg:

```
$ # Some text
$ lorem="Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur
adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt"
# Split at the commas, putting the pieces in the array phrase
$ split phrase "," "$lorem"
# Print the pieces in a way that you can see the elements.
$ printf -- "--%s\n" "${phrase[@]}"
--Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet
-- consectetur
adipisicing elit
-- sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

**Notes:**

1. Any function or script does have a status return, which is a small integer; this is what is actually returned by the `return` and `exit` special forms. However, the status return mostly works as a boolean value, and certainly cannot carry a structured value.

Comment: +1. Might mention namevars as a technique for more interesting cases (in bash 4.3+ or ksh93 where they're available).

Answer (score 1):

#### hello.sh

```
declare -a array       # declares a global array variable
array=(
    "hello world"
    "goodbye world"
)
```

#### other.sh

```
. hello.sh
tmp=( "${array[@]}" )  # if you need to make a copy of the array
echo "${tmp[0]}"
echo "${tmp[1]}"
```

---

If you truly want a function to spit out values that your script will capture, do this:

#### hello.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(
    "hello world"
    "goodbye world"
)
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

#### other.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./hello.sh | {
    readarray -t tmp
    echo "${tmp[0]}"
    echo "${tmp[1]}"
}

# or
readarray -t tmp < <(./hello.sh)        
echo "${tmp[0]}"
echo "${tmp[1]}"
```

Comment: Ought to at least make the caveat (that the latter code doesn't work with array values containing literal newlines) explicit.